# Can someone improve the recursive implementation of indexOf in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I've been working on a Java summer assignment and there was a problem on recursively implementing the indexOf method in Java. Here is what I have so far:

```
public int rIndexOf(char ch, int fromPos)
{
    int charPos = fromPos;

    if (charPos >= myString.length() || myString.equals(""))
        return -1;
    else if (myString.charAt(charPos) == ch)
        return charPos;
    else
        return charPos + rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1);
}
```

I seem to get values that are completely wrong, so I can only imagine it's a problem with incrementation or counting, but doesn't my code increment charPos by +1 each time? Or does it have to do with ASCII values of characters?

Also I was wondering if the line "charPos = fromPos" was necessary at all. Could I have just used fromPos throughout my code or would that violate the "pass-by reference not value" thing?

Comment: Have you tried simply stepping through your code in a debugger, to see where its behaviour diverges from what you expect?

Comment: Why do you do `return charPos + rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1)`? You simply need `return rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1)`.

Comment: Wouldn't this implementation be efficient if you got the remaining length of the string and split it in half and call recursion till the required character is found (or not found)? All you are doing is incrementing by one and calling recursion, I don't see the advantage of doing this through recursion other than to say that you used recursion. Isn't the point to find it faster through recursion?

Comment: @Ali: Are you talking about threading?

Comment: No, not threading, but I'm thinking of the time complexity in this situation and would be n-time the same as your algorithm and the same as simply looking through each character so... ignore my comment.

Comment: also you should handle null strings and minus parameters for frompos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could *absolutely* have used `fromPos` all the way through your code. Java never passed by reference, and you're not even changing the value of `charPos` anyway.

It's unclear why your final return statement *adds* `charPos` to the return value of the recursive call. Why isn't it just:

```
return rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1);
```

? After all, suppose it finds it at position 3 - that's going to return 3, so you don't want to add 2 to the 3 in the previous call, then add 1 to the 5 and end up with 6...

Comment: oh wow that was embarassing, thanks. so i've been adding charPos over and over

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
return charPos + rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1);
```

is flawed. Let's say myString is "the sun" and you call `rIndexOf(' ', 0);` Then you end up with:

`0 + 1 + 2 + 3` instead of 3. Since charPos is incremented each time and you add it to itself. You should just change that line to:

```
return rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

your last line is wrong, try this?

```
return rIndexOf(ch, charPos + 1)
```

also, this will create a huge stack in memory, not very efficient.

Comment: I would presume the reason for the assignment is to learn what happens when you recur as opposed to efficiency. :-)